# Constrain a variate to never be zero

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random

Is it possible to impose a constraint on the generation of a variate so that it cannot be zero? For example, I have expressions like this:

```
changeDistribution = 
  MixtureDistribution[{1, 4, 1}, {NormalDistribution[-10, 2], 
    NormalDistribution[0, 3], NormalDistribution[10, 2]}];

changeValues = Round[RandomVariate[changeDistribution, 60]]

{12, 3, -10, 12, 1, -2, -1, -1, 2, -10, -11, 6, 13, -4, 1, 0, -1, -1, \
-9, 4, 5, 12, 14, 0, 3, -11, -10, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, -9, -7, 8, 2, 1, \
9, -1, 10, 5, 7, 9, 2, 9, -10, -10, 5, 10, 2, 12, 0, -1, -11, -9, -5, \
5, 0, 1}
```

As you can see, the distribution sometimes generates zero values. I would like to exclude zero values so that some non-zero value is always produced.

Comment: Perhaps the simplest thing would be to select the nonzero entries from the distribution you have. It's the `Round` that is causing the zeros... remove that and it will just be the mixture of Gaussian's.

Comment: You might want to look at `TruncatedDistribution[]` or `CensoredDistribution[]`.

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of zeroes or is there a fundamental problem with your distribution (as per J.M). If its just the zeroes you can do something like `changeValues /. x_ /; x == 0 -> 0.01`.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on the suggestion by J.M.,

```
mdist = MixtureDistribution[
  {1, 1},
  {
  TruncatedDistribution[{1/2, \[Infinity]}, changeDistribution], 
  TruncatedDistribution[{-\[Infinity], -1/2}, changeDistribution]
  }]
```

Then

```
Count[Round[RandomVariate[mdist, 10^6]], 0] // AbsoluteTiming
```

returns

```
{0.62015, 0}
```

meanng it takes about .62 seconds to generate $10^6$ random variates, none of which are zero.